# Formly template field attribute with some html and a model value

Tags: ngx-formly

Setting up my form fields in json but have problem to show readonly information from model/formState within the json field definitions.

This works in angular-formly:

```
 "fieldGroup": [
    {"template": "<span>Status: {{model.status}}</span>",
     .....

  ]
```

but not in ngx-formly. A simle thing but please help me :)

`'Status: {{model.status}}'` is displayed instead of for example `'Status: Ready'`